# pyspark py4j create java string array

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, py4j

I want to call the `main` method of the FAT jar from Pyspark.

Here is the entrypoint of the main method of the jar (Scala):

```
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    // codes
  }
}
```

In order to invoke above method, I need to create an `Array[String]` using pyspark's py4j:

```
str_array = sc._jvm.java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(sc._jvm.java.lang.String, 3)
str_array[0] = "228"

loaded_class = sc._jvm.java.lang.Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().loadClass("com.mycompany.Main")
loaded_class.main(str_array)
```

And this is the error I get:

> Py4JError: java.lang.String._get_object_id does not exist in the JVM

With plain Py4j, I could have created string array using:

```
from py4j.java_gateway import JavaGateway
gateway = JavaGateway()
gateway.new_array(gateway.jvm.java.lang.String, 4)
```

I tried to pass object array to main, but that didn't work:

```
ob = sc._jvm.java.lang.Object()
ob_array = sc._jvm.java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(ob.getClass(), 3)
ob_array[0] = "228"
loaded_class = sc._jvm.java.lang.Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().loadClass("com.mycompany.Main")
loaded_class.main(ob_array)
```

fails with error:

```
Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o516.main. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method main([class [Ljava.lang.Object;]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:274)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

How do I create the string array to invoke main method in PySpark ?

Answer (score 2):

To convert some python list of strings (`arr`) to java string array in pyspark you can use the function `toJStringArray` bellow:

```
def toJStringArray(arr):
    jarr = sc._gateway.new_array(sc._jvm.java.lang.String, len(arr))
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        jarr[i] = arr[i]
    return jarr

# Usage example:
java_arr = toJStringArray(['string1'])
```

I run this code in the azure databricks. So the `sc` is a predefined global for the spark context.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the plain Py4j, can you try creating it using :

```
str_array = sc._jvm._gateway.new_array(sc._jvm.java.lang.String, 4)
```